# Can you tell me why my manifest.json is not detected?

Tags: php, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I do call him with the link :

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
```

And the file is at the root level.
When i open the source code and click the link, it does open.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Mon systeme</title>
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
```

Here is the beginning

```
{
    "short_name": "MiniSys",
    "name": "MiniSysteme",
    "start_url": "/index.php",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#FFE9D2",
    "theme_color": "#FFE1C4",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/img/icons/icon-72x72.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "72x72"
        },
```

The only weird thing i can see, is in the dev tool of chrome. The tags are mixed up. But i don't know if it means a thing ? Any idea ?

[the page in the dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzFtf.png)

Comment: _Validate_ your HTML, that should tell you why the head element is getting closed prematurely. https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Comment: Thank you. I tried and the source code is validated : "Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show."

Comment: Is the fact that the page is built by PHP using MVC pattern (require view.php files) a potential problem ?

Comment: No, it does not matter how the page is assembled on the server side, all that matters is what the client eventually receives. // Did you validate by URL, or just a copy&pasted version of the source code?

Comment: I copy&pasted :) So now i tried by URL and i have errors. But i don't understand since the errors seems to be coming from the page assembled on the server side :  Error: Element link rel="manifest" not allowed as child of element body in this context. But it IS on the <head> tags when i look at the source. And not in the dev tool. I'm loosing it...

Comment: Browsers will implicitly close the head and open the body element, once anything that is not allowed inside of head occurs, such as f.e. plain text outside of any tags. Check if you have any “invisible characters” or byte sequences before that link element.

Comment: I didn't find any invisible characters. Any way to be sure ? I alors tried to put the <link> right after the <title> but it doesn't change anything. I even put the <link rel=manifest"> first but then the <head> seems empty on the server side page.

Comment: Do you have this on a publicly available URL we can check?

Comment: Yes, i'm testing it here : http://jattends.nikubik.com/

Comment: I can’t spot anything directly either, when I copy&paste the source code into a hex editor. But the validator error message is peculiar, in that it says _“Element name `link rel="manifest"` cannot be represented as XML 1.0.”_ - it says `link rel="manifest"`  was the element name here, but that should only be `link`. So maybe some invisible character between `link` and `rel`? I don’t see any, but those can easily get lost when copy&pasting from the browser to a text editor. Try and re-type that whole line again, to exclude any stuff that might have worked its way in there via copy&paste.

Comment: Wow, that was it ! Crazy error. I retyped the line and it detects instantly. And then i had errors in the manifest file, i erase all space characters and it worked too. Thank you veeeery much, i would have never thought of something like that.

Comment: Now i need to make the Service Worker ... works. It seems the http URL is a problem because it needs HTTPS.